# Experiencing memory leak using TMatchCollection/TMatch

Tags: delphi

I'm with a problem here while using the Delphi Regex records. This is my problem code:

```
function CrawlThread.CrawlLinks: bool;
var
  Matches: TMatchCollection;
  Match: TMatch;
  i: integer;
begin
Matches:= TRegex.Matches(code, frmCrawler.Edit2.Text);
      if Matches.Count > 0 then
      begin
        i:= 0;
        for Match in Matches do
        begin
          SetLength(CrawledLinks, i + 1);
          if (POS('https://', Match.Value) = 0) then
            CrawledLinks[i]:= 'http://' + Match.Value
          else
            CrawledLinks[i]:= Match.Value;
          inc(i);
        end;
        Result:= true;
      end;
      Matches:= TRegex.Matches(code, frmCrawler.Edit3.Text);
      if Matches.Count > 0 then
      begin
        i:= 0;
        for Match in Matches do
        begin
          SetLength(FollowLinks, i + 1);
          if (POS('https://', Match.Value) = 0) then
            FollowLinks[i]:= 'http://' + Match.Value
          else
            FollowLinks[i]:= Match.Value;
          inc(i);
        end;
        Result:= true;
      end;
```

This code gets called multiple times inside threads, if I comment it, I get like 26MB on memory usage, and not growing up... When I use it, I start around 50MB (what is not a problem), but it keeps growing up like 1MB per minute (in 1 min this code gets called hundreds of times).

Using the *ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:= true;* I get this output:
[image]

It's almost the same when commented or using the code, so I don't believe it explain the 1MB per minute when using the code. Of course the UnicodeString leaks bother me, but as I get them even when not using the code, I don't think they are the problem.
Is there any idea on why that code is consuming so much memory?

Comment: This code doesn't produce those leaks. Please make a [mcve] and ask again.

Comment: Yeah I know it's hard to understand with that code. But like I said, when commented, I don't get that huge memory consuming growing up every minute... You sure that this code don't produce those leaks? And why the ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown don't show me more leaks when using/not using that code? Maybe is common to the TRegex consume huge memory (even without leaks)?

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Or if you want to solve the problem yourself, get FastMM and debug the leak allocation stack traces.

Comment: Maybe you need destroy object Matches. Matches.Free

Comment: @androschuk.a don't guess, those are records and not objects

Answer (score 1):

1. I dont think any of the shown code is leaking, since [TMatchCollection](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.RegularExpressions.TMatchCollection)  and [TMatch](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.RegularExpressions.TMatch) are pure records.
2. I have seen similar build-up of memory due to allocation of strings. But it must stabilize after a while, unless they are f.ex added to a `TStringList` without ever cleaning it.
3. That leads me to the next: The message box speaks about 2 x `TStringList` that are never freed. Have you tried so search your project for all `TStringList.Create` and made sure there are matching `TStringList.Free`? 
   Likewise for `TCriticalSection` and `TIdHashMessageDigest5`?
4. Just to be sure: in the above code it seems its a method inside a Thread class? If so, it will lead to errors referring to the components `frmCrawler.Edit2.Text` and `frmCrawler.Edit3.Text` in the VCL thread.